# AS3: Can't convert DataEvent.data to XML (throws error, that is not well-formed)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Uploading a file, i want to have an XML response from server.

So, in php, i do:

```
header("Content-type:text/xml");
echo"<whatever/>"; // any 100% valid XML
```

in flash, i use `FileReference` class and `FileReference.upload()` method

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, FileSelected);
file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, uploaded);

...

function FileSelected(e:Event)
{
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest(Main.baseURL+"/upload.php");
    req.method="POST";
    try{file.upload(req,"userfile")}
    catch(err:Error){Main.err("Can't upload",err,e)}
}

function uploaded(e:DataEvent)
{
    var s:String=e.data;
    trace(":"+s+":"); //output :<whatever/>: as expected
    var xml:XML=new XML(s); // fails with Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
}
```

Seems like `DataEvent.data`contains invisible garbage, that prevents it from parsing... 
My current solution is to manually cut off first char (0xFEFF):

```
function uploaded(e:DataEvent)
{
    var s:String=e.data.slice(1); // if i manually cut it off - all works
    trace(s); 
    var xml:XML=new XML(s);
}
```

Comment: do a `trace(":" + s + ":");` to see if there is anything extra in it.

Comment: it contains 0xFEFF as first character. when i manually cut it off, all works, but i think it is not a _good_ solution

Comment: edit the post and add code to it

Answer (score 0):

`0xFEFF` is [zero width no-break space](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html). Try removing that xml `header` from the php code.

Comment: removed text/xml header, but the 0xFEFF remains, tried text/plain - same story

Comment: I'm out of options - trim it for the time being - until someone comes with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[UTF BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Whatever is generating that file you're trying to upload should be configured *not* to add it.